# Windows Phone WebBrowser slow startup

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have an application that opens a webpage in WebBrowser but it takes more time than normal browser to startup. Once it has opened the first page, browsing speed is ok. Whats the difference between them and any idea about how to fix ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you might have done any massive processing before opening webbrowser,you just need to do this:

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = //your Uri
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing it has nothing to do with code. You should check what kind of connection you are using in you'r phone. Or the webpage has a lot of script or images, which typically takes time to load to your phone webbrowser control